# ERROR: No matching distribution found for ipython==7.18.1

Tags: python-3.x, django, ipython

I uploaded a Python app to Heroku. In my requirements.txt file I have a line for ipython==7.18.1 but Heroku seems unable to retrieve it, I don't understand whether the problem is with the versions of python and ipython and which version i should use,so they match

The complete error thrown is:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipython==7.17.0 (from -r /tmp/build_76afe907/requirements.txt (line 32)) (from versions: 0.10, 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.13, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 4.0.0b1, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.1.0rc1, 4.1.0rc2, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.2.0, 4.2.1, 5.0.0b1, 5.0.0b2, 5.0.0b3, 5.0.0b4, 5.0.0rc1, 5.0.0, 5.1.0, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.2, 5.3.0, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.5.0, 5.6.0, 5.7.0, 5.8.0, 5.9.0, 5.10.0, 6.0.0rc1, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.4.0, 6.5.0, 7.0.0b1, 7.0.0rc1, 7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.2.0, 7.3.0, 7.4.0, 7.5.0, 7.6.0, 7.6.1, 7.7.0, 7.8.0, 7.9.0, 7.10.0, 7.10.1, 7.10.2, 7.11.0, 7.11.1, 7.12.0, 7.13.0, 7.14.0, 7.15.0, 7.16.0, 7.16.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ipython==7.17.0 (from -r /tmp/build_76afe907/requirements.txt (line 32))

Comment: ipython `7.17.0` and `7.18.1` require Python 3.7+. The error message suggests you might be running Python 3.6.X on Heroku. See the docs for [how to specify a Python runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes).

Comment: Also, note the mismatch between `7.18.1` in your question and `7.17.0` in the error message. That suggests to me that you have changed the version in `requirements.txt`, but have not committed and pushed that change yet.